# Getting back bad strings from user32.dll EnumDisplayDevices

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I am trying to get the names of my monitors from user32. With what I have so far all I get returned is in Chinese characters. I'm not sure why, any help would be appreciated.

```
    public static SafeNativeMethods.DISPLAY_DEVICE GetDevices()
    {
        SafeNativeMethods.DISPLAY_DEVICE d = new SafeNativeMethods.DISPLAY_DEVICE();
        d.Initialize();
        if (SafeNativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(null, 1, ref d, 0))
            return d;
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException(GetLastError());
    }

public static class SafeNativeMethods
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int cb;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string DeviceName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceString;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int StateFlags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceKey;
        public void Initialize()
        {
            this.DeviceName = new string(new char[32]);
            this.DeviceString = new string(new char[128]);
            this.DeviceID = new string(new char[128]);
            this.DeviceKey = new string(new char[128]);
            this.cb = (ushort)Marshal.SizeOf(this);
        }
    }



        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
        public static extern Boolean EnumDisplayDevices(
            [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
            String lpDevice,
            [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            Int32 iDevNum,
            [In, Out]
            ref DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice,
            [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            Int32 iHaveNoIdea
        );
}
```

This code returns a device name of `屜尮䥄偓䅌㉙` could anyone please explain why and how to get the normal name from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Chinese characters" [usually means you tried to interpret a ASCII string as Unicode](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140930-00/?p=43953) (UTF-16).

Try adding a `CharSet` property to your `EnumDisplayDevices` declaration.

Comment: I had a declaration set to Auto, changing it to Ansi solved it, thank you!

Comment: Or avoid the potentially lossy, round-tripping and use CharSet.Unicode, the native Windows API character encoding (UTF-16) for the native Windows API character set (Unicode).

Comment: .NET strings are natively Unicode, so you should always use Unicode APIs for marshaling whenever possible

Comment: The core issue are inconsistent `CharSet` attributes. While the `DISPLAY_DEVICE` structure uses `CharSet.Auto` (which expands to `CharSet.Unicode` at runtime on all supported versions of Windows), the `EnumDisplayDevices` function doesn't have a `CharSet` attribute set, and defaults to `CharSet.Ansi`. The solution is to use `CharSet.Auto` on both, or better yet, `CharSet.Unicode`. You aren't going to run on a system that doesn't use Unicode, and the latter is evaluated at compile time, so there is no runtime cost involved as is the case with `CharSet.Auto`.